# How to create a dynamic LINQ query where clause

Tags: c#, linq

How would I create a where clause with multiple ORs based off a List?

I know it won't work, but here's what I'm trying to achieve. I haven't found a suitable method for doing it yet. For every one of the strings passed in, I need to add an OR where clause. The list could contain multiple tag strings and I need the query to add an OR where clause for each of them.

```
public void GetItems(List<String> tagsToGet){
    var tagQuery = from tag in ParseObject.GetQuery("Tag")
                   foreach(string tagToGet in tagsToGet){
                            where tag.Get<string>("name") == tagToGet || // next loop
                   }
                   select tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with method chain:

```
public void GetItems(List<String> tagsToGet){
    var tagQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("Tag");

    foreach(string tagToGet in tagsToGet)
    {
            tabQuery = tabQuery.Where(w => w.Get<string>("name") == tagToGet).AsEnumerable(); || // next loop
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't there need to be some sort of tagQuery += tagQuery.Where...? I know that's not supported. Setting tagQuery again would just overwrite the previous method. (I don't have access to Visual Studio this weekend so I can't test it.

Comment: You are just chaining methods `query.Where(...).Where(...)`. The solution in the answer below will also work btw.

Comment: I got ya, you're only modifying the Where property. I'll give both solutions a shot later this weekend when I get home. Thanks for your help, Vsevolod!

Comment: For clarification, this would add each Where clause as an OR operator or an AND operator? ex: where [bool] OR where [bool]

Comment: @LeviFuller it will behave as and AND, so now I see that this will not suite you. Check out Eris solution as it will suit your needs 100%

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
where tagsToGet.Contains(tag.Get<string>("name"))
```

or possibly

```
where t=> tagsToGet.Any(ttg => String.Equals(ttg, t.Get<string>("name"), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Obviously you can replace the comparison with any other way you prefer.

Another alternative, more linq-tastic:

```
var tagQuery = from tag in ParseObject.GetQuery("Tag")
               join tagToGet in tagsToGet
                 on tagToGet equals tag.Get<string>("name")
               select tag;
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll have to test it out once I get home. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). The second example should fit your requirements:

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

If querying with Entity Framework, change the last line to this:

```
return objectContext.Products.AsExpandable().Where (predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Dynamic LINQ. Get NuGet package System.Linq.Dynamic and see an example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/dynamic-linq